# scrapy login to imdb

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, imdb

I have scrapy code that looks into lists related to a given title and then downloads Other titles ratings from first page of each list. It is working fine.

However

Is there any possibility that I can make this code to login with my imdb login and then download my own ratings from those lists?

Here is the code:

```
class lisTopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'ImdbListsSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    titleLinkNum = 'tt0120852'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.imdb.com/lists/'+titleLinkNum
    ]
    # def ???(self, response):
    #     return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
    #         formdata={"username": "example@gmail.com","password":"example",}
    #         callback=self.parse)

    #lists related to given title
    def parse(self, response):
        listsLinks = response.xpath('//div[2]/strong')
        for link in listsLinks:
            list_url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('.//a/@href').get())
            yield scrapy.Request(list_url, callback=self.parse_list, meta={'list_url': list_url})

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="flat-button next-page "]/@href').get()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)            

    #Link of each list
    def parse_list(self, response):
        list_url = response.meta['list_url']
        myRatings = response.xpath('//div[@class="ipl-rating-star small"]/span[2]/text()').getall()

        yield{
            'list': list_url,
            'ratings': myRatings,
        }
```

Comment: Mind that one of the conditions that users of IMDB agree to as they register is: “Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.” — https://www.imdb.com/conditions

Comment: I need it for personal use sir.

Comment: I’m no lawyer, and I do not work for IMDB, but the terms and conditions that you accept when you register a user account are those, and there is no exception for personal use. If you value your account data, you might not want to risk getting your account suspended or deleted. If it is for personal use, to be on the safe side, I recommend that you ask them for permission before you start scraping the site.

Comment: I tried to contact them, the form asks to select commercial use for licensing.

Comment: Also, you should be able to export your IMDB data through other means. See https://letterboxd.com/about/migrating-from-imdb/ or https://www.wikihow.com/Export-Your-IMDb-Custom-Lists-to-a-CSV-File

Comment: I don't want to export my lists. I want to export my rated movies from other Public lists. This will enable me to find a list that depicts the highest of my ratings. So I can use that list to get recommended movies of my taste.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the thing you want is [`def start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) which allows you, instead of Scrapy, to compose the initial `Request` object that kicks off the crawl. Their example even more-or-less matches your pseudocode

Alternatively, instead of using `FormRequest` to submit credentials, you can separately login via your browser, grab the authentication cookies, and provide those via `start_requests` in case there is any weird stuff around login (such as reCaptcha, two factor authentication, etc):

```python
def start_requests(self):
    return Request(self.start_urls[0],
                   cookies={'whatever-cookie': 'whatever-value'})
```

and ensure you have [`COOKIES_ENABLED`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std-setting-COOKIES_ENABLED) in your spider's `settings.py`

Comment: Hi Mdaniel. I have done some work on this and at last found that there is an element in login form that scrapy can't collect as it is loaded via javascript. Will I have to learn splash or selenium etc just to grab that one element value, or there is some other way like collecting the value manually and pasting in scrapy code. This value keeps changing every login. Here is the situation of my project currently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611585/scrapy-formrequest-login-to-imdb-involving-javascript-form-field